# android kotlin - allow service run in background

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I have small, simple App with one service named MyFirebaseService.kt that only fetch notification data from Firebase and build notification. I only want to allwo this service works in background to fetch all firebase data and create notifications 24h/7 and avoid Android to kill this App/service. Which permissions do I need to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: There’s no permission for that. Android is very strict about services trying to do work more often than necessary because of battery use. Use WorkManager to schedule your work.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sounds like an answer ;)